# FACEBOOK GRAPH API time range setting does not works

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm trying to use api explorer tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ to get the spend amount for each ad inside my business account using this query

> act_000000000000/insights?fields=unique_impressions,spend&level=ad

but the tool seems not to understand the time-range filter and any of these methods are ininfluent

- ...&time_range[since]=2016-02-15&time_range[until]=2016-02-16
- ...&since=1456873200&until=1456873200
- ...&time_range{since=>2016-02-15,until=>2016-02-16}

Comment: You are accessing a field. Pretty sure that doesn't support time ranges

Comment: Yes, it is :(. 
To your knowledge, is there a way to get the spend amount for entire business account in a particular time range, also for each ad, ad_group, campaign or any other grouping type?

Answer (score 0):

Try following syntax:

...&time_range={"since":"2016-02-15","until":"2016-02-16"}

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
&time_range[since]={date.set('1982-12-12').format('yyyy-MM-dd')}&time_range[until]={date.today}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.